# CAS Central Authentication Service can access google, office365

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, cas, google-workspace

I want to build an Central Authentication Service on my website help users can access all my organization's service: Email and Drive using Google Suite for Education, Office 365, LMS and LCMS system... Student sign in one-time can access all service (eg. Email from Google).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is configure one identity provider (say Azure Active Directory) as the master and then configure the other (Google) as the subordinate. I don't know if Google supports that or not, but Azure AD does. Information on that is here: [Tutorial: Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) integration with Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial).

Okta is another product that solves this type of problem, but that adds more complexity.